# Transparent Menu to colored Menu on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, menu

I am definitely a beginner at js,I would like a Transparent Menu and when scrolling down a smooth transition happens from transparent to white with a box shadow.
but the code js doesn't work

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=document.getElementById('play');
var x=window.pageYOffset;
var see =function () {
    if (x >30) {
        a.style.background=" white";
    }else{
        a.style.background="transparent";
    }
    window.addEventListener("onscroll",see);
}
</script>
```

```
<header>
        <div class="menu" id='a'>
            <ul>
                <li><b>About</b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
```

```
.menu {
  background: transparent;
  margin-left: 320px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you get the `x` on scroll?? Instead you just store it once on DOM ready. Move that variable into the `see` function. Makes sense?

Comment: like that ?? if (window.pageYOffset>30) , but still doesn't work , and thank you for reply

Comment: No, this one: `var x=window.pageYOffset;`  why you've set it outside the `see` function? The `x` variable in JS will not automagically update. You need to update its value inside the `see` function since that's the function that's called on `"scroll"` event.

Comment: Also, you need to place `window.addEventListener("onscroll",see);` **after (outside)** of the `see` function

Comment: I really don't know but its still doesn't work :

Comment: var a=document.getElementById('play');
    function see() {
    if (window.pageYOffset>30) {
        a.style.background=" white";
    }else{
        a.style.background="transparent";
    }}
    window.addEventListener("onscroll",see);

Comment: Make sure to place your `<script>` right **before the closing** `HERE!! </body>` tag.

Comment: may the prob here :<header>
  <div class="menu" id='a'>
   <ul>
    <li><b>About</b></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header>

Comment: i did sir but really still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

- Place the `x` definition **inside** the `see`  function
- Place `window.addEventListener("onscroll",see);` **after! (outside)** the `see` function
- Use the `"scroll"` Event name

```js
var a = document.getElementById('play');

function see() {

  var x = window.pageYOffset; // This one goes inside
  
  if (x > 30) {
    a.style.background = " white";
  } else {
    a.style.background = "transparent";
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", see); // This one goes outside
```

Also, styling should go into CSS, not dispersed around your JS files.
Use Element.classList.toggle() to toggle a predefined CSS class:

```js
const EL_play = document.querySelector("#play");

function see() {
  var x = window.pageYOffset; // This one goes inside
  EL_play.classList.toggle("is-active", x > 30);
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", see); // This one goes outside
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#play {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

#play.is-active {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="play">PLAY</div>
<p style="height: 300vh;">Long element to force scrollbars...</p>
```

Comment: thank you sir but I really why but both of them doesn't work